# default method in Java 8 interface

Tags: java, interface

Suppose I have 3 methods (same name, different parameter, same return type), is there a way I can define one default method which implement the 3 methods (`Foo` in my example)?

**Previous implementation**

```
public interface testFoo {
    public int Foo (int a);
    public int Foo (int a, int b);
    public int Foo (int a, int b, int c);
}
```

**New Implementation**,

```
public interface testFoo {      
    default public int Foo (int a) {
        return a+1;
    }

    default public int Foo (int a, int b) {
        return b+1;
    }

    default public int Foo (int a, int b, int c) {
        return c+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean implement the 3 methods? You can call the other abstract methods in your default ones if that's what you need

Comment: @bali182, I mean if there is a way to implement one default method for the 3 overloaded methods? I post my code to clarify. My updated code has 3 default methods for each overloaded methods, and wondering if a solution define one default method, for 3 overloaded methods? thx.

Comment: Why do you need the abstract ones if you want to implement them in place? Just have the defaults then! But no, this won't compile

Comment: What you've posted doesn't make sense. What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: @khelwood, I updated post with my previous implementation and new implementation, in my new implementation, I implemented 3 default methods, wondering if there is a solution to implement 1 default method to cover 3 overloaded `Foo` methods? My current solution is using 3 default methods, one for each overloaded `Foo` method.

Comment: @bali182, my posting is a bit confusing and I updated post with my previous implementation and new implementation, in my new implementation, I implemented 3 default methods, wondering if there is a solution to implement 1 default method to cover 3 overloaded `Foo` methods? My current solution is using 3 default methods, one for each overloaded `Foo` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
public interface TestFoo {
    public int Foo (int a);
    public int Foo (int a, int b);
    public int Foo (int a, int b, int c);
}

public interface TestFooTrait extends TestFoo {      
    default public int Foo (int a) {
        return a+1;
    }

    default public int Foo (int a, int b) {
        return b+1;
    }

    default public int Foo (int a, int b, int c) {
        return c+1;
    }
}

class TestFooImpl implements TestFooTrait {
  // I don't have to impelemt anything :)
}
```

You can also freely use your abstract methods in the defaults:

```
interface FooWithDefault {
    public default int Foo (int a) {
      return Foo(a, 1, 1);
    }

    public default int Foo (int a, int b) {
      return Foo(a, b, 1);
    }

    // Let implementations handle this
    public int Foo (int a, int b, int c);
}
```

Comment: Hi bali182, I updated post with my previous implementation and new implementation, in my new implementation, I implemented 3 default methods, wondering if there is a solution to implement 1 default method to cover 3 overloaded `Foo` methods? My current solution is using 3 default methods, one for each overloaded `Foo` method. In your code, you still have 3 default methods.

Comment: I ask if there is a way to implement one default method for all overloaded methods since the interface I am working on has tens of overloaded methods, want to see if there is a simplified solution to add one default methods for all overloaded implementations.

Comment: Still unclear what you are asking, but I added all possible things that I can think of and might be related to your question :)

Comment: Thanks for the update, and I vote up for your reply. In your implementation, is there a way you can have only one default method in interface `FooWithDefault ` to cover 3 overloaded methods `Foo`? This is my question. :)

Comment: How do you want to have one method to cover all 3 cases? You can have the 3 argument method as default and the other ones abstract if you want to. If you would post an example of how you want your interface to look like and what kind of functionality do you expect that would be great.

Comment: You can't have default arguments in java if that's what you are asking. Like `int foo(int a = 1, int b = 2, int c = 3)` is not part of java.

Comment: Thanks, looks like if I have N overloaded methods, I need to implement N overloaded default methods in interface, correct? (appreciate for your help, mark your reply as answer.)

Comment: No problem. You don't _have_ to have all methods as default. You can also implement them in a class that implements your interface. If you have 3 overloaded methods, then you most likely have those because you want the user of your code to be able to omit some parameters. That's why I suggested to leave the overload with the most parameters abstract (let the actual implementor class take care of it) and just call it from the other simplified overloads

Comment: Thanks bali182, if my purpose if just to provide default implementation to resolve the problem of in case customer who implement the interface does not know how to implement the methods -- then I have to implement the default methods for the overloaded methods one by one, no short cut? :)

Comment: You probably have to then :( If there is nothing common in the overloaded methods then yes. But think about j8 interfaces as abstract classes without fields or constructors!

Comment: What do you mean `j8` bali182? The terms seems a bit advanced and modern to me, :))

Comment: Sorry, just java 8 =) I just meant that with the addition of default methods the java 8 interfaces became more like abstract classes. Except they can't have any fields or constructors.